# Filtering based on a range of names from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I'm trying to filter on range of names, without adding them manually, not only one name like right now, from the `Pos_data` to `T_Data`

My code:

```
   Dim category As Range
    
   With Worksheets("Pos_Data")
    
        Set category = .Range("U2")
        
   End With
    
    With Worksheets("T_Data")
    
       With .Range("A1:CP1503")
        
         .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=category, VisibleDropDown:=True
            
       End With
        
        
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Names appear in the column U of `Pos_Data`

Question is: how to have a filter that picks all the names from column U and then applies it in T_Data Column N

[Like here, I've got names and without manually writing them in the code I would like to filter on them in a new tab column N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r61pC.png)

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? It would help to include some sample data to show how you're trying to apply the filter and how it specifically relates to your question.

Comment: Question is: how to have a filter that picks all the names from column U

Comment: I added a picture, but I didn't see any need to do so. I thought my question was pretty clear. Sorry if not

Comment: Or it doesn't make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must construct an array of your names from the values in Column U. This example will hopefully give you a start.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterForNames()
    Dim categories As Range
    Dim categoryList As Variant
    
    '--- build an array of the names in the filter
    With Worksheets("Pos_Data")
        Set categories = .Range("U2:U5")
        ReDim categoryList(1 To categories.Cells.Count)
    
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(categoryList)
            categoryList(i) = categories.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next i
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("T_Data")
       With .Range("A1:CP1503")
         .AutoFilter Field:=14, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=categoryList
       End With
    End With
End Sub
```